# Accessing a checkbox value in the save_post hook in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a situation where posts can be saved and users can be notified when a post is saved if the "Send alert" checkbox has been checked. I don't want the checkbox to be saved as it needs to be checked only when you want an alert sent out. This allows the admin to save, edit, etc. without any difficulties.

So far, I have added the checkbox in the publish box for a post:

```
function createCustomField(){
  $post_id = get_the_ID();

  if(get_post_type($post_id) != 'jobs'){
    return;
  }

  $value = get_post_meta($post_id, '_send_alert', true);
  wp_nonce_field('send_alert_nonce_'.$post_id, 'send_alert_nonce');
  ?>
  <div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="_send_alert" /><?php _e('Send alerts', 'pmg'); ?></label>
  </div>
  <?php
}
add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'createCustomField');
```

And have the save_post hook setup as well which needs to check for the checkbox if it is checked or not and then send out alerts if it is.

```
function save_job_callback($post_id){
  global $post;

  if($checkbox){
    //send out alerts here   
  }
}
add_action('save_post','save_job_callback');
```

The question I have is - How do I access the value of the checkbox within the save_post hook?

[image: Checkbox in Wordpress publish box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the checkbox value as a parameter to the function:

```
function save_job_callback($post_id,$checkbox=$_POST['checkbox']){
  global $post;

  if($checkbox){
    //send out alerts here   
  }
}
add_action('save_post','save_job_callback');
```

Comment: This only works because PHP is a crazy language... correct parameters are **`do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );`**

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox has a [`checked` state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox), if it's present the metadata is saved, if not it's deleted.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="coding" name="interest" value="coding" checked>
```

The `nonce` is used so our `save_action` doesn't fire everywhere, only when our code is running.

The action `save_post` receives three arguments [`($post_id, $post_object, $update)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and we must check for posted values with `$_POST` after being sure our code runs on the right places.

Working code:

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'checkbox_so_43970149' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_so_43970149', 10, 3 );

function checkbox_so_43970149(){
  $post_id = get_the_ID();

  if(get_post_type($post_id) != 'jobs'){
    return;
  }

  wp_nonce_field('send_alert_nonce_'.$post_id, 'send_alert_nonce');

  $value = get_post_meta($post_id, '_send_alert', true);
  $checked =checked($value, '_send_alert', false);
  ?>
  <div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="_send_alert" <?php echo $checked; ?> name="_send_alert" /><?php _e('Send alerts', 'pmg'); ?></label>
  </div>
  <?php
}

function save_so_43970149( $post_id, $post_object, $update ) {
      if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
          return;

      if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['send_alert_nonce'], 'send_alert_nonce_'.$post_id ) )
          return;

    if ( 'revision' == $post_object->post_type )
        return;

    if ( isset( $_POST['_send_alert'] )  )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_send_alert', $_POST['_send_alert'] );
    else 
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_send_alert' );
}
```

Comment: So I can just leave out the update_post_meta and delete_post_meta statements since I don't want to save the _send_alert checkbox value.